# "Две такиХ фигуры" или "две такиЕ фигуры"?

Tags: склонение

Найди здесь *две таких фигуры*, из которых можно составить прямоугольник.
Как правильно: *две такиХ фигуры* или *две такиЕ фигуры*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Две такие фигуры.

Answer (score 1):

Найди здесь "что?" Две **такие фигуры**.

Answer (score 1):

1. При существительных мужского и среднего рода, зависящих от числительных два, три, четыре (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола. Например: ...Офицеры ели жадно, без разговоров, наверстывали за два потерянных в боях дня (Шолохов); Два крайних окна в первом этаже закрыты изнутри газетными листами... (А.Н. Толстой).
2. При существительных женского рода в указанных условиях определение чаще ставится в форме именительного падежа (или совпадающего с ним винительного при неодушевленных существительных) множественного числа. Например: две большие комнаты выходили окнами в сад; купила четыре фарфоровые чашки; на изгороди из трех жердей сидели три женские фигуры (А.Н. Толстой); По этим дорогам двигаются две большие колонны немцев (М. Бубеннов).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь лучше "две такие". Помимо всего прочего надо еще и математический контекст учитывать. А он родительного не любит.
А еще лучше - вообще убрать слово "такие".